# Singular cohomology of a limit of topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $(X_\lambda)$ be a filtered projective system of topological spaces, $X = \varprojlim X_\lambda$ and let $R$ be a finite ring, for example $R = \mathbb{Z}/l$. Assuming that $(X_\lambda)$ is sufficiently nice (see below), is the a canoninal isomorphism of singular cohomology groups
$$
 H^n(X,R) \cong \varinjlim H^n(X_\lambda,R) \ ?
$$
In my case, "sufficiently nice" has the following meaning. I consider a projective system of (possibly singular)  complex varieties $(Y_\lambda)$ with finite transition morphisms and let $(X_\lambda) := (Y_\lambda(\mathbb{C}))$ be the corresponding system of complex spaces.

Comment: Given that even the inverse limit of the doubling map on the circle is a dyadic solenoid, I doubt this will be true. Certainly it is not true for CW complexes by this example, but I'm not familiar enough with complex geometry to say for the case of complex varieties. What you really want is Cech cohomology, which was built to handle such limits in exactly the way that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. While the circle is not a complex variety, the complex numbers without the origin would be. Could you elaborate how your counterexample works ? I am not familiar with the dyadic solenoid.

Comment: It's the space $S = \varprojlim(S^1\overset{\times 2}{\leftarrow} S^1 \overset{\times 2}{\leftarrow} \cdots)$. Or alternatively, it's the set you get by mapping a solid torus inside itself with a 'double wrapping' around the hole, then iterating this and taking the intersection. [This gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)#/media/File:Solenoid.gif) on wikipedia is a good illustration of the second definition. [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)).

Comment: I guess something very similar happens with the punctured complex plane and the map $re^{i\theta} \mapsto re^{2i\theta}$ whose inverse limit is just the product of a solenoid and the real line.

Comment: For a seemingly trivial example, take the limit you get by mapping $2^{n+1}$ disjoint points into $2^n$ points (each point has exactly two preimages). The inverse limit of this system is the Cantor set and so it has uncountably many path components, meanwhile the limit of the $0$th cohomology groups should only have countably infinite rank I believe.

Comment: Since finite sets of points are indeed complex varieties, this gives a counterexample to my statement. Seems like I should consider sheaf cohomology instead. Thank you very much for your help.